# Website Tracking from Magento to OroCRM is not working

Tags: php, magento-1.9, event-tracking, orocrm

I am new to OroCRM, using the OroCRM 1.9.0 and Magento 1.9.2 versions. I was able to integrate Magento with OroCRM and Sync Customer and Order data from Magento to OroCRM. Now trying to track my magento customer interactions like products viewed, pages visited, etc., using the website tracking feature configured as mentioned in the document https://www.orocrm.com/documentation/index/current/user-guide/marketing-tracking-website-records but doesn’t work.
Also Installed the available extension http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/orocrm-tracking.html but still it is not working for me.
Can any one help me out in tracking the magento ecommerce and sync to OroCRM.
Thanks

Comment: Same here. I looked at github repo and I saw that the last time source code was modified is 2 years ago. So maybe that code is not working anymore

Answer (score 2):

As i understood you create Tracking Website record on OroCRM with mandatory fields Name, Identifier, Url (url of your magento site). Also you should modify magento settings in System -> Configuration -> OroCRM -> Oro Tracking. Set Enable to Yes, Site Identifier is the same with identifier in OroCRM and Service Host Name is your OroCRM url.